# Can't keep CSS change via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple "select" - show below.

```
<label>Best way to reach you?</label><br>
    <select id="contactMethod">
        <option value="wp">Work Phone?</option>
        <option value="cp">Personal Cell Phone?</option>
        <option value="email">Email?</option>
        <option value="Im">Instant Messanger?</option>
    </select>
<button onclick="showHidden()">Which way?</button>
```

the object I wish to show is in the HTML with the following properties:

```
<label>E-mail Address:</label>
<input id="email" type="text" style='display:none'>
```

I then have a .js file with the following function.

```
function showHidden() {
    var dropSelection = document.getElementById("contactMethod").value;
    console.log(dropSelection)

    if(dropSelection == "email") {
        document.getElementById("email").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

I then have the id listed within my CSS as the following:

```
#email{ display:none; }
```

The goal is to "show" the email text box when the "email" option is selected from the `<select>` above.

As of right now, I'm simply printing what was selected, so I can know for sure that I'm getting the right values to run the if statement against. That being said, when I select the email option, it literally flashes the email text box but immediately reverts back to a hidden state.

### UPDATED CODE

```
<label>Best way to reach you?</label><br>
    <select onchange="showHidden()"  id="contactMethod">
        <option value="select">Select...</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="phone">Work Phone</option>
        <option value="cPhone">Cell Phone</option>
        <option value="Im">Instant Messanger</option>
    </select>
```

### MODIFIABLE FIELDS

```
<label id="emailLabel">E-mail Adress:</label>
<input id="email" type="text">
<label id="phoneLabel">Work Phone Number</label>
<input id="phone" type="text">
<label id="cPhoneLabel">Personal Cell Phone Number</label>
<input id="cPhone" type="text">
<label id="IMLabel">Instant Messenger Name</label>
<input id="Im" type="text">
```

### JS

```
function showHidden() {
    var dropSelection = document.getElementById("contactMethod").value;

    if(dropSelection == "email") {
        document.getElementById("email").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("emailLabel").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else if(dropSelection == "phone") {
        document.getElementById("phone").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("phoneLabel").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else if(dropSelection == "cPhone") {
        document.getElementById("cPhone").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("cPhoneLabel").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else if(dropSelection == "Im") {
        document.getElementById("Im").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("IMLabel").style.display = "inline";
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can use [hide()/show().](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

Comment: Why click a button for the event? You should have an eventListener on the change event of the dropdown. You could also just toggle a css class that has a display: none property.

Comment: I tried fiddling around with the onchange event, but it doesn't seem to work. I have it set as such:

<select onchange="showHidder()" id="contactMethod">
    <option value ="email">Email?</option>
</select>

Comment: Seem to get the onchange working. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function showHidden(){
    var dropSelection = document.getElementById("contactMethod").value;
    console.log(dropSelection)

    if(dropSelection == "email"){
        document.getElementById("email").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#email{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<label>Best way to reach you?</label>
<br>
<select id="contactMethod">
  <option value="wp">Work Phone?</option>
  <option value="cp">Personal Cell Phone?</option>
  <option value="email">Email?</option>
  <option value="Im">Instant Messanger?</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="showHidden()">Which way?</button>
<br>
<label>E-mail Adress:</label>
<br>
<input id="email" type="text" display="none">
<br>
```

I don't see any problem, it works fine.

Comment: I don't understand...when I test it within chrome, it flashes the text field and then is hidden again.....I see it spitting out the "email" within the console of chrome, but it's as if the css is not retaining the change made via the if statement.

Comment: I tried the code in jsfiddle and console kept saying "showHidden" not declared.....

Comment: I'm getting no errors, it's appears to just not retain the newly changed property of the css. Which is why I'm more pretty confused.

Comment: In js fiddle it wont work that way.
I don't understand why it does that to, that's pretty wierd